# Web Page Zooms in on Windows

Tags: css, ionic-framework

So I am building a PWA using the [Ionic PWA ToolKit](https://ionicframework.com/pwa/toolkit).  Now it displays as it should on my mac but I recently tried it on 3 different laptops running windows and everything just seemed zoomed in.

This is how it appears on my mac and should appear:
[image]

And this is how it displays on windows (other laptops):
[image]

This is my CSS:

```
    /*
* =============================================================================================
* Content Section
* =============================================================================================
*/
app-bus-home  {
  background: url(../assets/img/banners/bus.jpg) no-repeat bottom/cover;
  min-height: 730px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;

}

app-bus-home ion-grid {
  max-width: 1200px;
}

app-bus-home ion-text h1 {
  margin-top: 90px;
}

app-bus-home h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}

app-bus-home ion-img.bus {
  width: 500px;
  margin-top: 65px;
}

date-picker {
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
    top: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And this is the JSX layout:

```
render() {
        return [
            <ion-grid align-items-start>
                <ion-row>
                    <ion-col>
                        <ion-text color="light">
                            <h1 class="font-light animated slideInLeft">BUS <strong class="font-black">TICKETS</strong></h1>
                            <p class="font-light animated slideInLeft">xxxxxx</p>
                            <p class="font-light animated slideInLeft">xxxxxx</p>
                        </ion-text>
                        <ion-img class="bus animated zoomIn" src="../assets/img/bus.png" />
                    </ion-col>
                    <ion-col size="4" padding>
                        <bus-search class="animated slideInRight"></bus-search>
                        <date-picker availableDates={this.availableDates} actionUrl={this.actionUrl} showHeader={true} showButtons={true} class="animated"></date-picker>
                    </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your page isn't responsive, so it means that you can't see it in the same way on different devices. To optimize the visualization on several devices, i suggest you to use '%' instead of 'px' in your css.

In alternative you can use libraries like Bootsrap to do it. Bootstrap offers lot of classes to make your page responsive. Usually I use the following documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/default.asp .

Comment: It is responsive. Ionic uses Flexbox to build it's responsive grid which is what I'm using. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid

Comment: Ionic might be responsive but your CSS is not. You hardcode all your sizes in pixes. Your screen shots are completely different resolutions. The windows computer you used must have a 720p screen (or you resized the browser) where as the Mac is almost 4k.

Comment: no that's not it, I took out all the harcoded sizes and still even the background image was positioned differently.   Note it's the PC that is 4k not the mac and when you zoom out to 90% on the PC it looks like how the mac displays it at 100%.